# Testing a redirect outside of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I have a helper module with a method that fires off `redirect_to` if the current user does not have permission to visit a web page.

I am getting a `NoMethodError` error when running the tests, since the helper does not actually have a redirect_to method. I have tried stubbing out redirect_to like this:

```
it "redirects the user to the user's langing page if the user doesn't have permission" do
  allow(helper).to receive(:current_or_guest_user) { test_user }
  expect(helper).to receive(:redirect_to)
  helper.require_permission :view_admins
end
```

but I get a long long error that the helper does not implement `redirect_to`.

Is there a way to stub out this method?

Comment: redirect_to is a action controller method therefore can only be used in a controller

Comment: Yeah, but this is a module that will be included in the controller, so it works just fine - I'm just not sure how to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an `anonymous` controller in your spec and include your module in it. When you've got that, you can test it like a normal controller action/method. So, add something along the lines of this to your spec:

```
controller(YourController) do
  include YourModule

  def index
    render text: 'body'
  end
end
```

I don't know whether your method is a `before_action` or not, but it seems like it is since you're testing whether the user has the required `view_admins` permission.

So, when the user has the required permission, your spec should be something like this:

```
context 'when the user has the required permission' do
  before do
    # make sure the user has the required permission
  end

  it 'the user will see the rendered text' do
    get :index
    expect(response.body).to eq 'body'
  end
end
```

And when the user doesn't have the required permission they'll be redirected to the path you've defined. So, something like this:

```
context 'when the user does NOT have the required permission' do
  before do
    # make sure the user does NOT have the required permission
  end

  it 'the user will be redirected to the specified path' do
    get :index
    expect(controller).to redirect_to your_specified_path
  end
end
```

More information about `anonymous` controllers can be found [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller).